# Why does ethereum use only GPU for computation? Why mobile processing powers are not used?

Tags: mastering-ethereum

I want to make a project based on mobile (mining) using its computing power (as done by electronium). But i am unable to find any framework or platform for that.
Please help me out if anyone has a suggestion or solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum does not *use* or require GPU for mining (computation). GPUs just happen to be the best suited readily available components for the calculations.

You *can* mine with your CPU but it will be really inefficient as CPUs are designed for different calculations. There are some coins which can be mined effectively with your CPU but they are really rare. Furthermore, mobile CPUs are less effective than regular CPUs.

Nevertheless, mining is not typically about the amount of hashing power. If everyone has similarly crappy hashing power the network may work just fine. I'd imagine the problem in this case is guaranteeing that nobody uses better resources for the mining - if everyone else mines with their mobile phones and one person uses his CPU/GPU rig for the mining, the mining process becomes centralized and the network loses its decentralized nature.

Electroneum does not actually mine with CPU either - it's only simulating mining: https://electroneum101.com/how-to-mine-electroneum-with-a-mobile-phone/ .